# Replicating AutoFill function in web browser?

Tags: windows, browser

Looking for a way to replicate Excel's AutoFill function and be able to utilize it on web browser or open window.

There's a number of limitations due to restrictions on the PC.

I'd like to be able to type a number into the first box in the red highlighted column then have it auto populate the next consecutive number in each text box.

I know I am able to run .cmd/.bat files to do basic functions.

Is there a way to program one to be able to read what I input or read highlighted text then be able just +1 to it?
Even if tabs multiple times to move to the next box.

[Example Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW9ds.png)